# Alternative to Angular Two Way Data Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using the Two Way Data Binding feature of angular.js, but this is the only feature I use.

Example: http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/twowaydatabinding/

So my question:

Is there an alternative, which offers an easy setup (like angular) and only has this one feature, two way binding?

Comment: I don't understand the question. More importantly, how can a **function** be two-way binded? Two-way binding is for variables. For the function, you can use the isolate scope `&`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best place to ask for library recommendtation. It's for asking question about "why this code doesn't work"? Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ See Bullet 4 in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You may want to consider [Ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for something closer to [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) which does two way binding very well, and leaves out most of what Angular.js brings to the table.

Here is [an example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) comparative to your AngularJs example for your reference.

Hope this helps you some.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for a templating language, like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Or for a more elaborated and recommended library, [RactiveJS](http://www.ractivejs.org/)